# How can align vertices using a curve?

Tags: mesh, bezier-curves, vertices

i have a mesh and a bezier curve, and i want align individual vertices to curve, it is possible?

[image: align-vertice-to-curve-blender-lionel-bino-blender]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can convert the curve to a mesh (best if you keep the original as well, there is a setting for that), and then snap to the edges of that mesh. The mesh resolution of the converted result depends on the **Preview U** value in the curve shape tab:

[image: preview_U]

Once that is set high enough, you can select the curve and hit <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> to get the **convert to** popup. Select **Mesh** from it. Then, set the Blender snapping mode to **Edge** and snap your vertex to the curve. See this animation for clarity:

[image: snapping to curve]

Comment: @aliasguru Much smarter method than mine! +1 from me.

Answer (score 4):

If you have the equal number of vertices and curve segments you may snap one to another using ***snap tool***. Click the *magnet* icon and set the *snap element type* to ***Vertex***. Enter *Edit Mode* of the mesh and align vertices with curve's points.
[image]